# How to join two dataset<T> in Spark Scala when one key is in sequence without explode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-dataset, seq

## Problem Statement

I have three case classes:

```
case class Trip (val board: String, val off: String)
case class Description(val key: Int, val airline: String, val trips : Seq[Trip])

case class TripDuration (val airline: String, val board: String, val off: String, val duration: Int)
```

And two Datasets:

```scala
Dataset<Description> DescriptionDS
Dataset<TripDuration> TripDurationDS
```

What I want is to obtain a Dataset with type

```scala
case class TripWithDuration (val board: String, val off: String, duration: Int)
case class DescriptionExtended(val key, val airline, val tripsExtended: Seq[TripWithDuration ])

Dataset<TripDurationExtended> TripDurationExtendedDS
```

so, joining by  in order to add the **Duration**.
All with Dataset API.

## Possible solutions

I know that this can be done with a mixed approach, where a first explode is done on the **Seq** column, and then join + group by on Key.

This may be unoptimal, if the number of columns is big, as in the group by you have to specify the grouping function for every colum.

### Datafame Approach

```scala
DescriptionDS.select($"key", $"airline", explode( $"trips").as("trip") )
.join(TripDurationDS, Seq($"airline", $"trip.board", $"trip.off"))
.select(<existing cols>, struct(<with board, off, and duration>).as("tripExtended"))
.groupBy($"key").agg(first($"airline"), ..., collect_list($"tripExtended")) // FOr all the columns
.as[TripDurationExtended] // Or somehing similar
```

### Dataset Approach

```scala
DescriptionDS
.joinWith(TripDurationDS, DescriptionDS("airline") === TripDurationDS("airline")
       and <???> )
```

## Question

*** Is it possible to so it with that approach ? ***

*** What is - if exists - the api to do that with typed approach ? ***